# PHP Won't INSERT INTO MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am having problems inserting information from a form into a MySQL database.

When I click the "submit" button, the URL changes from domain.com/register-form.php to domain.com/register-script.php and it doesn't add anything to my database table.

After I found out my original piece of code wasn't working, I decided to simplify it to the bare minimum without escape_strings and password hashing, and the basic version still didn't insert into my database.

I'm certain that I'm just overlooking something very basic, but I can't figure it out for the life of me. All of the database information is correct, and the user has full permissions.

NOTE: Please ignore the lack of security in the script and user rights. This is a very simplified test that didn't work.

My file structure is a single directory consisting of the following three files: `database.php`, `register-form.php`, `register-script.php`.

My database table `Users` is structured as:

> `user_username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
>   `user_password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
>   `user_email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL

database.php:

```
<?php
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $user = "databaseuser";
    $password = "databasepassword";
    $database = "databasename";
    $prefix = "";
    $database = mysqli_connect($hostname,$user,$password,$database);
?>
```

register-form.php

```
<?php require 'database.php' ?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form name="register" action="register-script.php" method="post">
<label>Desired Username: </label>
<input type="text" name="newuser_username" placeholder="Desired Username">
<label>Password: </label>
<input type="password" name="newuser_password" placeholder="Password">
<label>Email: </label>
<input type="email" name="newuser_email" placeholder="Email Address">
<input type="submit" name="register_button" value="Sign Up!">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

register-script.php

```
<?php
    require 'database.php';

    if(isset($_REQUEST['register_button'])){
        $username = $_REQUEST['newuser_username'];
        $password = $_REQUEST['newuser_password'];
        $email = $_REQUEST['newuser_email'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_username,user_password,user_email) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email')";

        mysqli_query($database,$sql);

    }

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `error_reporting` and `mysqli_error`  yet?

Comment: are you getting any error? have you tried replacing `$_REQUEST` to `$_POST`

Comment: a small amount of debugging would go a long way

Comment: @Dagon A small amount of sanitation would too... http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Well, I added the mysqli_error, deleted the files from the host, uploaded the files with the error reporting, and now it's working. I wonder if it might have been a problem on the host's side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure that your phpmyadmin user name and password are correct in default case it is root and blank.

Check Your database connection with mysqli_connect_errno() that actually you are connected to database or not.

Check with mysqli_num_rows() that your query returning some results or not.

and at the end close mysqli connection.

Comment: Thanks Buddy... And please follow object oriented approach to implement db releted task using mysqli extension.